# How to use waitForAngular() in protractor test scripts?

Tags: protractor, angular8

I wanna implement browser.waitForAngular() in all by e2e test scripts instead of explicit waits. Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to call .waitForAngular() function manually in your tests, since it will be executed automatically before every your action on the page - http://www.protractortest.org/#/infrastructure

However, this does not means you can remove your explicit waits from code. Your tests will be much more stable if you will be using both - automatic wait for angular AND explicit waits for needed elements conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I need to contact you so will send you an email. If possible can we talk over phone if u dont mind?